# SQL Left Join on Self

Tags: mysql, select, join

I know this has been asked before and I have tried the techniques I've seen here. But it's just not working.

I have a table of 'People' which looks like this

PersonID, PersonName, PersonYOB, PersonCOB, FatherID

```
1    Fred Astaire    1963    USA    2
2    Bruce Astaire   1933    USA    NULL
3    Adele Astaire   1961    FR     2
4    Gene Kelly      1965    IT     NULL
5    Lucy Astaire    1935    USA    NULL
```

What I would like to do is a SELECT where the Father name comes from the father's PersonID. I also have the Mother but I've removed that for simplicity. Once I get Father to work I'll add Mother back in.

My current SELECT looks like this

```
SELECT p.*, f.PersonName AS FatherName FROM People 
LEFT OUTER JOIN People f ON
p.PersonID = f.FatherID
```

All of my People appear but the FatherName is always NULL.

Fred Astaire should show Father ID 2 and f.PersonName as Bruce Astaire. The same is true for Adele Astaire (his sister).

What am I missing?

Comment: you can use `inner join` for this purpose...

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with [inner join](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-self-join/) because you are trying to join the table with itself....

```
SELECT p.*, f.PersonName AS 'FatherName' FROM People p   //here is the p you forgot
    INNER JOIN People f ON
    p.PersonID = f.FatherID
```

Answer (score 0):

Your join condition is in incorrect. Change as below.

```
SELECT p.*, f.PersonName AS FatherName FROM People p
LEFT OUTER JOIN People f ON
p.FatherID= f.PersonID
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That was just the syntax correction I needed.